# Why is PHP code in Google analytics code not properly executed?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I am using this code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-xx', 'auto');
<?php 
   if (is_single()){
      echo "ga('set', contentGroup1, '".get_the_author()."');n";
      $category = get_the_category();
      if ($category && !empty($category[0]->cat_name)){
         echo "ga('set', contentGroup2, '".$category[0]->cat_name."');n";
      }
   }
?>
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The aim is here to send both the category name and author from my Wordpress website to Google Analytics (Content Grouping).

However, when my website is being viewed my source code (in the head section) still shows the php tags. How can I ensure that the PHP code is properly parsed and the author / category information is correctly inserted?

Comment: What's the file extension of the file including your php code? If it's not php, then php won't process it

Comment: Hello André, it's included on any regular page created by my Wordpress theme. Any other php code works just fine.

Comment: You mean that you can see the php tags inside your script?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The author and category information aren't properly inserted.

Comment: You've not shown us the code which does the include. Have you reset your opcode cache since you deployed this?

Comment: The code added to my head-section of my wordpress install is shown at the top of the question. No, I haven't reset my opcode cache.

Comment: While I don't know why your code isn't parsed I can at least tell you that you use a wrong quotation mark (in the nested if condition at the end of the echo). Might be just a typo in your example, but as written this should result in a parse error.

Comment: Hello Eike, I have corrected this error, but the code still isn't being parsed.

Comment: you're dumping text from php into a JS context. you SHOULD be using `json_encode()` to guarantee that whatever wordpress is spitting out becomes **VALID** javascript. consider what happens if your author name contains a `'`?

Comment: Hello Marc, could you help me by creating the correct code? Unfortunately my programming skills are not good enough to translate your suggestion into valid code!

Comment: What file is this php code in? what url is being requested? What _exactly_ is the rendered source? This question doesn't really have anything to do with google analytics.

Comment: Place this whole part in the footer.php. And empty the field in the WP admin panel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem you are describing means that the server is not parsing the codes you provided.

In a basic environment that would be caused by using a file type that is not associated with PHP by default (such as .html) and is not being parsed.

In your case, you mention you are using wordpress, I would guess that you have inserted this code in some field that has protection and instead of parsing your code it is then outputting it literally instead.

What you can do is find the file and update it manually instead of using the wordpress UI. Additionally, make sure the file *will* be parsed by the preprocessor.

Also, if you are using the WordPress wysiwyg editor to add the php code then there are plugins available which can let you run/parse PHP code added there.

Comment: OR .. there are plugins available for WordPress which lets you run PHP code added in wysiwyg editor ..

Comment: @SyedQarib sorry, I'm not very familiar with wordpress. Feel free to add to this answer!

Comment: no need to be sorry :) was just pointing it out, might be helpful for someone else ..